# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (DateTime Format yyyyMMdd:HHmmss)

Tags: c#

I have a date time format of `yyyyMMdd:HHmmss`. I receive the datetime from a device and I can confirm that the format is `yyyyMMdd:HHmmss`.

For example I get datetime as `20180331:162308`. I tried to convert to `03/31/2018 04:23 PM` format by using below code:

```
string localDateTime = 
  Convert.ToString(protocol.GetParameter(Parameter.localmdmdatetimestr_3043));

string formatString = "yyyyMMdd:HHmmss";

protocol.Log(
 "QA" + protocol.QActionID + "|DateTime|localDateTime" + localDateTime,
  LogType.Error, 
  LogLevel.NoLogging);

DateTime LocalDt = DateTime.ParseExact(
  localDateTime, 
  formatString, 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But instead get

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
>   error.

Comment: Dates have *no* format, they are binary values. If the result of `protocol.GetParameter(Parameter.localmdmdatetimestr_3043)` is a DateTIme value you don't have to convert or parse anything. Calling `Convert.ToString` without specifying a format results in a string with *your machine's local date format*.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to display your DateTime value in a certain way, use `.ToString(...)` on the **client** or on the display form and specify the format you want to use. Or change the locale used to display data. Or specify a format string to your controls or data binding statements. Don't try to "convert" the DateTime value. It doesn't have any format so the final value will be the same as the original

Comment: If you want to convert a DateTime value to local time or UTC time, use the appropriate `DateTime` methods

Comment: BTW `DateTime.ParseExact("20180331:162308", "yyyyMMdd:HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works just fine.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - a lot of what you've shown isn't relevant to the question, but you haven't provided code that we can copy, paste, compile and run to reproduce the problem for ourselves.

Comment: I think the problem is with leading and/or trailing white-spaces in input string.

Comment: As per @PanagiotisKanavos, if i put the string directly, i can get the value. but if i refer from localDateTime, i get error. If i not convert to string i get error on "cannot implicitly convert object to string"

Comment: @Jeeva `Convert.ToString()` does nothing more than cast to string if the result is a string wrapped as an object. Instead of using it, use `var string localDateTime = (string)protocol...`. What are the *contents* of `localDateTime` though? Any leading or trailing spaces? Unexpected characters?

Comment: From Surenthar P:`give us the log (protocol.Log) output for analyzing your code. I highly doubt the localDateTime string will be having leading spaces.`

Comment: @Jeeva [Convert.ToString()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1801) does nothing more than call `ToString()` on an object. That's why it's rarely used. [String.ToString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2658) simply returns the string itself. Don't look for weird conversion bugs. If parsing doesn't work, the results of `protocol.GetParameter` don't match the pattern. They may containg extra whitespace

Comment: @Jeeva to clean it up. just call `.Trim()`, eg `DateTime.ParseExact(localDateTime.Trim()....)`. If that doesn't work, *post the actual content* of  `localDateTime` in the question itself. There may be tabs, newlines or other invisible characters that you didn't notice

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for some reason, after i add .Trim()..i can get the right result

Comment: @Jeeva that's because the string contained extra characters. `Trim()` removed them

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement
string localDateTime = Convert.ToString("20180331:162308");

```
        string formatString = "yyyyMMdd:HHmmss";

        DateTime LocalDt = DateTime.ParseExact(
          localDateTime,
          formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(LocalDt);
        var test = LocalDt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: That's not what the question is about.